# Prove that the only nilpotent operator is 0?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if $\phi:V \to V$ is nilpotent, then its only eigenvalue is $0$.

I know how to prove that this for a nilpotent matrix, but I'm not sure in the case of an operator. How would I be able to relate $\phi$ to a matrix?

Comment: The $f$ you defined is not nilpotent (it is of order $2$).

Comment: Thanks, just realized i wasn't looking at the right thing

Answer (score 1):

$\phi$ is nilpotent iff here is $n$ such that $\phi^{n} = 0$.

Thus $\phi$ is a root of the polynomial $x^{n}$.

It follows that its minimal polynomial is a divisor of $x^{n}$, hence of the form $x^{k}$, for some $k > 0$.

Thus $0$ is the only eigenvalue.